# Given a div how to select all the contenteditable caret in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

When select by cursor dragging only one word is getting selected how can i select multiple words here by dragging in a given div

```
<div>
  <span contenteditable="true"> Hey </span>
  <span contenteditable="true"> I am </span>
  <span contenteditable="true"> Testing </span>
</div>
```

Comment: A *caret* cannot be selected. A caret is a singular entity - commonly a vertical thin line indicating where text can be currently typed

Comment: @vsync is there anyway i can solve this, by dragging it shoud select word from Hey I am to Testing

Comment: You surely mean simply `contentEditable` and not `contentEditable="{true}"`

Comment: I can select multiple words when running your code with no problem. What browser/OS are you on? I'm using Edge/Windows10. However I'm not sure where the syntax of contentEditable="{true}" came from.

Comment: Please thoroughly explain the steps done by the user until the end result. in as many details as possible

Comment: @vsync How to make this is a editor where we can hightlight the text by dragging the mouse and cursor , and i have updated the method 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: @AHaworth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content , i am talking about this sorry for the typo

Comment: So could you describe exactly what you are seeing? As I say, I can select one word or several so there seems to be no problem.

Comment: @AHaworth are you able to drag by cursor and select all the words inside the div by using the above code ?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @AHaworth try this https://jsfiddle.net/mayank20202200/7wc4135h/

Comment: @AHaworth I am not able to that in windows

Comment: Which browser? And what happens? Is one word selected? If so, with or without its spaces etc.

Comment: @AHaworth one word is only getting selected

Comment: Which browser???